# How can a one-shot System.Threading.Timer dispose itself?

Tags: .net, timer

I'd like to use a `System.Threading.Timer` to execute once. That timer is supposed to be deterministically cleaned up by calling `Dispose` as soon as it is no longer needed (which is when the callback fires).

The problem is that the callback cannot reliably obtain a reference to the `Timer`!

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed.");

    //Dispose the timer here, but timer might be null!
    timer.Dispose(); //BUG
}, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

The variable `timer` might not be initialized when the callback fires. This code doesn't work in all cases because it contains a race condition.

How can we use `System.Threading.Timer` to create a one-shot timer with deterministic cleanup?

(Better ways to create a one-shot timer/delay are out of scope for this question. I'm intentionally asking this in a specific way.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to the [constructor of Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149618(v=vs.110).aspx) that only receives a callback so that it will **pass itself** in the state parameter.  Use `Change()` to set it up immediately afterwards:

```
        System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer((state) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed.");

            // Dispose of the timer here:
            ((System.Threading.Timer)state).Dispose();
        });
        timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

If you don't like to use the `state` parameter you can also use closure variable like the code in the question does it. The key is not starting the timer with the constructor. Only start it after a reference to the timer has been stored.

Comment: That should do the job. The Task.Delay method has the same race condition I talked about. Also, they have a data race on the DelayPromise.Timer field.